# Can VSCode interact with the kernel of current Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In VSCode, a script with:

```
#%%
a = 3
```

creates a Jupyter cell. Running the cell starts Jupyter server and evaluates the code in Python Interactive window.

I would like to interact with this session and pass `print(a)` to it from a console, without modifying the Jupyter notebook. Is that possible? I cannot find a way to open a Python session in which `a` would be defined.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I honestly can't think how the GIL is relevant here. That will limit a single process. There's nothing stopping you from launching 50 independent Python scripts at once, then you're only at the mercy of the OS in dishing out CPU resources for each script

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds but that will be IPython; all it does is have a persistent namespace. The IPython kernel is _exactly_ set up for this, I just don't know specifically for Jupyter because I normally use Spyder.

Comment: Well Jupyter just uses the iPython kernel, so the answer should be the same between them. I guess I didn't know how iPython worked until now! I figured it was a modified interpreter but that's not at all how it works, so yeah, I see why you said the GIL doesn't seem relevant. For OP --> https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#decoupled-two-process-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest logging a suggestion from our GitHub:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues

This might be similar to what you're asking for.
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3101

This would allow you to type temporary code into the interactive window. If you didn't like it, you could delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You could call ipython's `%qtconsole` *magic command*

```py
#%%
%qtconsole
```

This opens up a **separate** jupyter qt-console window which points at the same kernel as the vbcode 'notebook'.

Comment: ...on the remote server running the kernel. Thanks, but this does not exactly solve it. :)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (Windows 10):

1. `conda install qtconsole`
2. `pip install PyQt6`
3. DOSbox run `ipython qtconsole` . . .  
   [image: qtconsole]
4. File > New Tab with Existing kernel , as shown above picture.
5. Select an existing kernel (.json file). I check variable value to know which one is the correct target or by the date-time of the .json files.

6. then you can do your experiments onto the existing .ipynb notebook.

Jupyter Lab is much much better. You can open any .py and select an existing .ipynb as its kernel. Then highlight anything on the .py and press Shift-Enter to execute the highlight. I have a .py that collects most useful code snippets and it keeps everything I tried. Why VS code can't do this？ Or it can actually already？